# How to set layout for extended view (programmatically)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I have Fragment that creates view. I need it to handle multi touch events.

**Fragment code:**

```
public class ControllerFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.controller_fragment, container, false);

        TouchEventView mView = new TouchEventView(v, container);
     //...
    }

    // ...
}
```

But main problem is that my view have no layout. It's simply black without buttons, textViews and other stuff that is in **R.layout.controller_fragment**

So, how should I set layout to my extended view?

**TouchEventView:**

```
public class TouchEventView extends View {

    public TouchEventView(View v, ViewGroup container) {
       super(v.getContext());
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that main problem was that TouchEventView extended View. It should extend same layout that is in R.layout.controller_fragment.

So I added LayoutInflater  to the constructor and passed it from the fragment. And then I inflated layout from the TouchEventView constructor. Now it looks like this:

**Fragment:**

```
public class ControllerFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.controller_fragment, container, false);
        TouchEventView mView = new TouchEventView(v, inflater);  
    //...
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Extended View (Layout):**

```
public class TouchEventView extends LinearLayout {

    public TouchEventView(View v, LayoutInflater inflater) {
        super(v.getContext());
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.smart_tv_controller_fragment, this, true);
    }
```